# Why gulp don't build a new file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I've add a new directive folder, but gulp don't build only .sass file.

```
gulp.task('default', function(){
    gulp.run('libs');
    gulp.run('templates');
    gulp.run('makeup');
    gulp.run('script');
    gulp.run('json');
    gulp.run('images');
    gulp.run('particles');
});


// ========== ALL SASS AND CSS FILES ==========
gulp.task('makeup', function(){
    gulp.src([
            // ALL ABOUT LIBS CSS FILES
            './public/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            './public/components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css',
            './public/components/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css',
            './public/components/animate.css/animate.min.css',
            './public/components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css',
            // BUZZ SASS
            './public/css/sass/*.sass',
            './public/js/directives/**/*.sass'
            ])
   .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
   .pipe(concat('build.css'))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/build/'));
});
```

in build.css no code that i add.

Tree folder:

[image]

What it could be? How to fix it?

Comment: Could you add error handler `sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError)` and check if it logs something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the base of your paths to `gulp.src`:

```
gulp.src([
    // ALL ABOUT LIBS CSS FILES
    './public/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    './public/components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css',
    './public/components/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css',
    './public/components/animate.css/animate.min.css',
    './public/components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css',
    // BUZZ SASS
    './public/css/sass/*.sass',
    './public/js/directives/**/*.sass'
], {base: './'}) // add it behind your array
```